# How to add policy file (.xml) in a SOAP request

Tags: php, laravel, soap

I am implementing a web service in a laravel web application. The web service server is using a secure connection. I keep getting 
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from ...
error. I think it is because I cannot attach the policy file (policy.xml) in the request. I am using SoapWrapper package by Artisaninweb to send the request. How do we attach the policy file to a request (SOAP).

Comment: I have already enabled openssl, curl, xmlrpc in php.ini

Comment: I could connect to the url, but when i try to access one of the methods, i am getting the "could not connect to host" error